# Java - Base64 Decode

Tags: java, base64

I have to decode the authorization header of an http request of the form `Basic bW9uTG9naW46bW9uTW90RGVQYXNz`

When I decode it [online](https://www.base64decode.org/), I got the correct result `monLogin:monMotDePass`.

When I try with my code :

```java
String valueDecoded = Base64.getDecoder().decode(request.getHeader("Authorization").split(" ")[1]).toString();
System.out.println(valueDecoded.toString());
```

I've got this result which is not correct : `[B@16d9ea61`

Is there anything wrong with my line ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the simplest way to print a Java array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/whats-the-simplest-way-to-print-a-java-array)

Comment: I don't get it :/

Comment: That `[B@16d9ea61` seems to be an object reference of a byte array, while you probably want its contents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't call `toString()` on a `byte[]`. You can construct a `String` by passing the `byte[]` to `new String`. Like,

```
String valueDecoded = new String(Base64.getDecoder().decode("bW9uTG9naW46bW9uTW90RGVQYXNz"));
```

I get `monLogin:monMotDePass`